# explain compass @SearchableComponent @SearchableReference

Tags: java, compass-lucene

both also used for annotating "foreign key" in jpa entity right?  I do understand `@searchablecomponent`,

let say we have  category and subcategory.   search subcategory will return category in this case of `@searchablecomponent`.  what about `@searchablereference` ? i cannot understand this one?  for case of `@searchablereference`, will searching for subcategory still return category ?

ref: http://www.opensymphony.com/compass/versions/0.9.0/html/core-osem-annotations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These annotations are part of the compass API, and have nothing whatsoever to do with JPA (or Hibernate, databases, etc). The concepts are similar, though.

If you annotate a property of `ClassA` with `@SearchableReference`, then Compass will store only the referred object's ID. It's similar to Hibernate's "many-to-one" or `@ManyToOne` relationship.

If you use `@SearchableComponent`, then Compass will "inline" all of the properties of the referred object when it stores it in compass, similar to Hibernate's `<component>` or `@Embedded`.

The similarity with Hibernate/JPA is strong, and it's where the terminology comes from.